# Composition animation in a custom Page control?

Tags: c#, xaml, animation, uwp

i've created a custom control that inherits from Page, to animate the NavigatingFrom event. However, I don't seem to be able to play the actual animation. This is my full AltPage.cs code:

```
public class AltPage : Page
{
    protected override void OnNavigatingFrom(NavigatingCancelEventArgs e)
    {
        //Set up the composition animation
        var _compositor = new Compositor();
        var _targetVisual = ElementCompositionPreview.GetElementVisual(this);
        var animation = _compositor.CreateScalarKeyFrameAnimation();
        animation.Duration = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 0, 300);
        animation.InsertKeyFrame(1.0f, 0f);


        _targetVisual.StartAnimation("Opacity", animation);

        //Give some time for the animation to start
        Task.Delay(18);

        //Get the page to initialize while the animation is playing
        base.OnNavigatingFrom(e);
    }
}
```

When I run the code, the line `_targetVisual.StartAnimation("Opacity", animation)` lifts a System.UnauthorizedAccessException. i'm told that "The caller is not allowed to perform this operation on this object". What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

> When I run the code, the line _targetVisual.StartAnimation("Opacity", animation) lifts a System.UnauthorizedAccessException. i'm told that "The caller is not allowed to perform this operation on this object".

The `Compositor` object needs to be got from any `Visual` of current Page. You can use the following codes to got a Compositor:

```
ElementCompositionPreview _compositor = ElementCompositionPreview.GetElementVisual(this).Compositor;
```

[Page.OnNavigatingFrom](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.ui.xaml.controls.page.onnavigatingfrom.aspx) was raised before Navigation, but we can't give a delay to prevent the page from navigating. When we are using `Task.Delay`, we need an `await` to let it work synchronously. But it will make the whole function runs asychronously(`async` will be added when using `await`). So,**if you put your codes in `OnNavigatingFrom`, you won't get the expected behavior**.

As a workaround, you can put your codes before [Frame.Navigate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/br242694(v=win.10).aspx?appid=dev14idef1&l=en-us&k=k(windows.ui.xaml.controls.frame.navigate)%3bk(targetframeworkmoniker-.netcore,version%3dv5.0)%3bk(devlang-csharp)&rd=true) like below:

```
Compositor _compositor = ElementCompositionPreview.GetElementVisual(this).Compositor;
Visual _targetVisual = ElementCompositionPreview.GetElementVisual(this);
var animation = _compositor.CreateScalarKeyFrameAnimation();
animation.Duration = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 0, 3000);
animation.InsertKeyFrame(0.0f, 1.0f);
animation.InsertKeyFrame(1.0f, 0.0f);

_targetVisual.StartAnimation("Opacity", animation);
await Task.Delay(3000);//Give some time for the animation to start
Frame.Navigate(typeof(NewPage));
```

Thus, you will get an animation  of page fading, and I have made a demo, that you can refer to:[CustomPageSample](https://github.com/elvisxia/CustomPageSample).